# Android: Trying to fetch the push() key id and extract the rating value from the child element

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a feedback app where the customer has to submit a rating (1-5) and that data pushes onto Firebase realtime database. The database in Firebase which looks like this -

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "-MCHoOShwgxPE3u2drjz" : {
      "Arpit Mundra" : {
        "name" : "Arpit Mundra",
        "rating" : 5
      }
    },
    "-MCHqbF4UvX02OYJNuPv" : {
      "Ankit Mundra" : {
        "name" : "Ankit Mundra",
        "rating" : 5
      }
    },
    "-MCHr-q_amx1vBJkyq2S" : {
      "Harsh Chauhan" : {
        "name" : "Harsh Chauhan",
        "rating" : 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to calculated the average of the `rating` of all the users which falls under user which again falls under the push() id. My question is how do I fetch the unique push() id to extract the rating value from it?

Here is the code -

```
package com.example.feedback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Score extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView avgScore;
    DatabaseReference dbRef;
    String mGroupID

    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.score);
        avgScore = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(mGroupID);
        mGroupID = dbRef.push().getKey();

        scoreRealTime();
    }

    public void scoreRealTime() {
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                double total = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    double values = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("rating").getValue().toString());
                    total = total + values;
                }
                double average = (double) total / snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                avgScore.setText(String.format("%.2f", average));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is throwing a NullPointerException error at String `double values = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("rating").getValue().toString());` line.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT - MainActivity.java -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    ImageView oneStar, twoStar, threeStar, fourStar, fiveStar;
    Intent intent;
    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    public void displayScore() {
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Score.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name =  findViewById(R.id.editTextPersonName);
        oneStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        twoStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        threeStar = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        fourStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        fiveStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        oneStar.setTag(1);
        twoStar.setTag(2);
        threeStar.setTag(3);
        fourStar.setTag(4);
        fiveStar.setTag(5);

        oneStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (name.length() == 0){
                    name.setError("Please enter your full name.");
                }
                else {
                    name.setError(null);
                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
                    //Fetch all values
                    String username = name.getText().toString();
                    String value = view.getTag().toString();
                    int rating = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    UserHelper helper = new UserHelper(username,rating);
                    reference.push().child(username).setValue(helper);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback submitted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sleep(2500);
                    displayScore();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't see where you are adding Users to the path of the query. You're almost certainly querying the wrong location.

Comment: @DougStevenson added the MainActivity code where I add users to the path. I am new to firebase and don't have much hang of it so can't really tell where have I gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

yu do not need to get the pushid. just get the snapshot of user. and then fetch the data from the user object like this.`

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

             databaseReference .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override

        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            double total = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){

          UserHelper helper = ds.getValue(UserHelper.class);

                double values =
             Double.parseDouble(helper.rating);

                total = total + values;

            }

            double average = (double) total / snapshot.getChildrenCount();

                avgScore.setText(String.format("%.2f", average));

             }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });`
```